# Parsing wikipedia page content and removing extra content

Tags: python, html, css

Was working on parsing wikipedia pages.We have to extract only the visible text part and ignore/remove other html tags,URLs,references to images, tables, formulas, and navigational components. The code below works fine, however, i wanted to know how to get rid of the tables such as contents tables on the page and also the references section towards the bottom of the page.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource-efficient"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for script in soup(["script", "style","[document]", "head", "title","table"]):
    script.extract() 
text = soup.get_text()
```

Comment: You're saying you have to strip various *tags*. Does that mean you want to delete just the tags or the contents of them as well? For example, should the contents of a table still be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're focusing on Wikipedia, don't bother with trying to parse the text. Luckily, Wikipedia provides the [`TextExtracts` extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts) to be used with the API. This URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Resource-efficient&prop=extracts&explaintext&exsectionformat=plain&redirects
gives you the response:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "redirects": [
            {
                "from": "Resource-efficient",
                "to": "Resource efficiency"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "36804997": {
                "pageid": 36804997,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Resource efficiency",
                "extract": "Resource efficiency is about maximising the supply of money ...<snip>... External links\nGreen Town: efficient community\nResource efficiency in environmental accounting"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part you're interested in is in `"extract"`.

Take a look at the parameters in the URL. `titles` takes one or more titles (separated by a `|`), `prop=extracts` uses the special extension I just mentioned to extract the plain text, `explaintext` makes sure we don't get HTML tags in the result, `exsectionformat=plain` replaces the sections with two newlines and `redirects` resolves redirects automatically (it's not mandatory, but a good option to have). If want to use another return format, use the parameter `format=xml` or something else.